# Example of a dense but not schematically dense open subset

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

We have the following theorem in algebraic geometry

> Let $X$ be a reduced $S$-scheme, $Y$ a separated $S$-scheme and $U\subseteq X$ a dense open subset. Then two morphisms $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ that are equal over $U$ must be equal.

I am trying to understand why these hypothesis are needed.

It is easy to see why $Y$ must be separable, otherwise I can take the affine line with double point at the origin and the two different inclusions of the usual line on it. These morphisms are equal on $\mathbb{A^1}\setminus \{0\}$ but not on the entire double line. Basically this example is the same as the one we have in general topology when $Y$ is not Hausdorff and the reason amount to the fact that the equalizer of $f$ and $g$ must not be closed.

But it has been harder for me to understand why the hypothesis for $X$ is needed.

It appears the reason is the existence of open subsets $U\subseteq X$ that are dense in the topological level but not in the sheaf level. So you can embed them inside a closed immersion $Z\hookrightarrow X$ where $Z=X$ as sets but $\mathcal{O}_Z=\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J}$ with $\mathcal{J}\subseteq \mathcal{Nil}(X)$.

I tried to construct such an open set but I failed.

Anyway, I looked in the literature and I saw that the right notion of dense open subset for schemes is called schemetically dense (or scheme theoretically dense), as can be seen in the [book of Görtz, Wedhorn](https://books.google.fr/books?id=XEiLudn6sq4C&pg=PA232#v=onepage&q&f=false) or the [Stack Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RA) and are exactly the ones that avoid this problem.

So now my question is

> What is an example of a dense open subset $U\subseteq X$ that is not schematically dense?

I tried to construct it with an affine $X$ and $U$ principal but it appears it must be something more involved than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $X = \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$ (i.e. a line with an embedded point at the origin) and $U = D(y)$. This is of course dense as a topological space, but is not scheme-theoretically dense, since $U\hookrightarrow X$ factors through $U\hookrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k[y] \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$.

Comment: Perfect example and very geometric! I was looking for exactly something like that.