# If a rational map extends, is the extension unique?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Can a rational map of schemes $X\leadsto Y$ be extended to more than one morphism $X\rightarrow Y$?

Comment: Yes, because of non-separatedness.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar  Thanks, i havent learned about separatedness yet, but I'm satisfied with that answer since it was just something i was idly wondering.

Comment: This post may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170788/